# Python 2D lists: sort 2D list in relation to other sorted 2D list

Tags: python, list, coordinates

I am trying to sort two 2D lists along with two lists, each relative to one of the 2D lists.

The two 2D lists are lists of coordinates captures from 2D and 3D looking something like this:

```
2D_list1 = [[0.1, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.2], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7]]
2D_list2 = [[0.5, 0.7], [0.5, 0.1], [0.2, 0.7], [0.8, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2]]
```

My first approach was to sort the lists and their relative lists by the coordinates with code like this:

```
2D_list1, relative_list1 = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(2D_list1, relative_list1), key=lambda k: [k[0][0], k[0][1]])))
```

but because the coordinates captured in 2D and 3D are not entirely the same i.e. they can vary by a tenth on both the x and y axis. This will sometimes lead to one list being sorted in another order than the other.

My thought now is that maybe there is a way I can sort the second 2D list and its relative list by how similar the coordinates are to the x,y sorted first list, but I have zero clue about how I would go around doing this.

My expected output from the example values would be:

```
2D_list1 = [[0.1, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.2], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7]]
2D_list2 = [[0.2, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.1], [0.5, 0.7], [0.8, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7]]
```

Any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed outcome formatting

Error from relative list sort:

```
relative_list2.sort(key=lambda x: sorted_list2.index(list2[relative_list2.index(x)]))
ValueError: array([[[37, 40, 40],
    [36, 39, 39],
    [36, 39, 39],
    
    [71, 74, 75],
    [71, 74, 75],
    [70, 73, 74]]], dtype=uint8) is not in list
```

TypeError

```
relative_list2.sort(key=lambda x: sorted_list2.index(list2[x]))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Best regards
Martin

Comment: I hope I'm understanding correctly, so you will like to sort the `2D_list2` in ascending order, but in accordance to whether there is similar element in the `2D_list1`?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I want it to be in ascending order, but with a tolerance looking if af element in 2D_list1 is almost the same as the one in 2D_list2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python variable names cannot start with digits, so I will call the lists list1 and list2.
You need a function to check how similar two coordinate pairs are.
A simple function is to take the sum of the absolute values of the differences of the two x values and two y values, so if the two coordinate pairs are (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) then the function should output abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)
This function gives the difference between two coordinate pairs, so you want the pair with the minimum - min() - difference
The python min() function accepts an argument called key, where we can enter this function. So code that works is:

```
list1 = [[0.1, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.2], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7]]
list2 = [[0.5, 0.7], [0.5, 0.1], [0.2, 0.7], [0.8, 0.2], [0.8, 0.7], [0.2, 0.2]]
#relative_list2 = list with same len() as list2

sorted_list2 = []
sorted_relative_list2 = []
for coords in list1:
    match = min(list2, key=lambda n: abs(n[0]-coords[0])+abs(n[1]-coords[1]))
    sorted_list2.append(match)
    sorted_relative_list2.append(relative_list2[list2.index(match)])

print(list1)
print(sorted_list2)
print(sorted_relative_list2)
```

This outputs what you want (the sorted list_2 is in the variable sorted_list2)

Comment: So if I wanted to sort the relative list along with list2 it would be something like: match = min(zip(list2, relative_list2), key=lambda n: abs(n[0]-coords[0])+abs(n[1]-coords[1])?

Comment: You mean you want list2 to be sorted instead of having a sorted copy?

Comment: I mean that I have another list called relative_list2 containing objects, these are in the same order as the original list2D_2. I want the relative list to match the order of the coordinate list like I do in the example with the ascending sorting.

Comment: If the relative_list2 also contains coordinate pairs, you can do this in the same way. I'll edit my answer

Comment: It does not, it contains point cloud objects, but the indexes of coordinates and objects are matching to begin with, so I just need the objects to move around the relative list when I sort the coordinate list.

Comment: oh ok ill change that then

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and hopefully it works. Is there a cleaner way of doing this like with the zip method?

Comment: I'm not sure about how you would use zip() but I have updated the code to make it a bit better anyway. What were you thinking of?

Comment: I guess I just hadn't thought of bringing in extra variables in the form of the sorted lists, so I was expecting a one liner like the example with using zip, but it works.

Comment: In your updated code I get a value error because the sort function is trying to find one of the objects in my relative list in the coordinates of the sorted list

Comment: can you copy and paste it?

Comment: Added it to the question section

Comment: sorry, i've corrected it now

Comment: No need to be sorry :D Testing now

Comment: It still tries to do something with the relative list in comparison to the coordinate lists, so I get a type error. Added it under the other error.

Comment: I have gone back to the old method because i think this will work

Comment: I mean that ive edited the answer

Comment: Understandable, I will do some testing and accept your answer, unless someone else chimes in. Thanks for your time and help, it has been greatly appreciated